# Javascript scroll and stop when in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
            function Scroll(aid){
                var aTag = $(\"a[name='\"+ aid +\"']\");
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
            }
```

But the problem is, that it scrolls down to the  tag, so it is in the top of the window. I did like to have it, so it only scrolls to the element so it is in the bottom of the window.

So you can see what is on top of the  element (like all the other content above it).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out how high the viewport is, and substract that:

```
var pos = Math.max(aTag.offset().top - $(window).height(), 0);
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: pos },'slow');
```

You might need to add a small offset.